# How to make background image for a div responsive?

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap-3

How could I use `img-responsive` of bootstrap to a `div` as follows:

```
<div class="fill" style="background-image:url
                                            ('./images/abc.jpg');">
</div>
```

While I am trying to add `img-responsive` class inside the `div` along `fill` it doesn't work. How could I make the background image for the above `div` responsive?

Comment: Do you want the background image fill the div completely (cropped) or do you want the background to scale to fit (letterbox)?

Answer (score 5):

```
div {
    background-image:url('./images/abc.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

1. If the background-size property is set to "contain", the background image will scale, and try to fit the content area. However, the image will keep its aspect ratio (the proportional relationship between the image's width and height):

   ```
            div {
                 width: 100%;
                 height: 400px;
                 background-image: url('img_flowers.jpg');
                 background-repeat: no-repeat;
                 background-size: contain;
                 border: 1px solid red;
                }
   ```
2. If the background-size property is set to "100% 100%", the background image will stretch to cover the entire content area:

   ```
           div {
                width: 100%;
                height: 400px;
                background-image: url('img_flowers.jpg');
                background-size: 100% 100%;
                border: 1px solid red;
              }
   ```
3. If the background-size property is set to "cover", the background image will scale to cover the entire content area. Notice that the "cover" value keeps the aspect ratio, and some part of the background image may be clipped:

   ```
         div {
              width: 100%;
              height: 400px;
              background-image: url('img_flowers.jpg');
              background-size: cover;
              border: 1px solid red;
             }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Look, there is a nice technique using background-size property

```
.fill {
    background: url(path/to/img.jpg) center center no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

This rule will make your background image cover all container space and adjust when scaling the window.

Answer (score 0):

Use `background-size` property to the value of `100% auto` to achieve what you are looking for.

**For instance,**

```
.fill{
   background-size:100% auto;
}
```